# TabBar without separators

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am trying to get rid of the vertical divider lines in between the TabButtons of a TabBar:[image: vertical separator lines]

Documentation states that

> TabBar consists of two visual items: background, and contentItem.

So if I understand correctly, the only way to achieve the desired look is to start over again and start using a Container as the base of my custom Component. Is that correct, or is there a way to build upon TabBar?

Comment: I recommend you to use fluid Qml plugin. İt is easy to make tabs and there is not such problem in fluid components.

Comment: Introducing a new plugin to a project to cure a single layout problem seems a bit much, no?

Comment: I think it is easy to build UI in the short time using this plugin :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set spacing to 0:

```
TabBar {
    spacing: 0
}
```